# Finding meta “description” using Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I was trying to pass a tab object `tabout` in order to find the description and title of the webpage.

When I was debugging the code with some breakpoints, it was returning value, but when I am running it, it's not returning the description.

Is there any problem with the code?

```
  function computeDescription(tabout)
          {
            var code = 'var meta = document.querySelector("meta[name=\'description\']");' + 
                       'if (meta) meta = meta.getAttribute("content");' +
                       '({' +
                       '    title: document.title,' +
                       '    description: meta || ""' +
                       '});';

            var desc;
            var message = document.querySelector('#message');

            chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabout.id,{code: code}, function(results) {

            if (chrome.extension.lastError) {
            message.innerText = 'There was an error injecting script :\n'+chrome.extension.lastError.message;
            }

            if (!results) {
             return;
            } 

        var result = results[0];
        // Now, do something with result.title and result.description
        console.log(result.title);
        console.log(result.description);
        desc=result.description;

      });

   return desc;

 }
```

Comment: This part works if I run it in Developer Console, it looks like the problem is somewhere else: document.querySelector("meta[name='description']")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're assuming that the callback you give to `executeScript` will execute before `computeDescription` returns. This is not true; `executeScript` executes asynchronously and your callback will *never* run before `computeDescription` returns.

In order to handle this, you need to to adopt the asynchronous model for your definition of `computeDescription`. Rather than returning a value, take a callback argument and call it when data is ready.

```
function computeDescription(tabout, callback) {
   var code = 'var meta = document.querySelector("meta[name=\'description\']");' + 
              'if (meta) meta = meta.getAttribute("content");' +
              '({' +
              '    title: document.title,' +
              '    description: meta || ""' +
              '});';
   var message = document.querySelector('#message');
   chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabout.id, {code: code}, function(results) {
     if (chrome.extension.lastError) {
       message.innerText = 'There was an error injecting script :\n'+chrome.extension.lastError.message;
     }
     if (!results) {
       callback();
     }
     callback(results[0].description);
  });
}
```

Then your usage similarly transforms from

```
console.log('Le description is: ' + computeDescription(tab));
```

to

```
computeDescription(tab, function(description) {
  console.log('Le description is: ' + description);
});
```